# Problem with right shift key on mac

Tags: mac

Hello I am experiencing a problem with the right shift key on my mac. When I press right shift + 2, for example, I should get just @. Instead I get @++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ with the plus going on forever. What is this problem and how would I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this an external keyboard or a built-in keyboard on a MacBook? Either way, attach another keyboard and see if that duplicates the issue. It may just be an issue with that shift key. Meaning replace the keyboard.

Comment: I had the same issue. I happened to have fixed this by physically removing the shift key and cleaning the membrane underneath. That seems to have worked.